# Current User not found

Tags: swift, getstream-io

After updating to version 2.2 when I try to use the TextToolBar I continue to get the "❌ The current user not found" error.

Here is my setup code:

```
Client.config = .init(apiKey: "ajbbcwn5bxms", appId: "64415")
Client.shared.setupUser(token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidXNlci1vbmUifQ.AW1xE4VpjzKTpcj3dEX3eLVeXUAoHtaqCEeqDCHYiuo") { result in
    // Do all your requests from here. Reload feeds and etc.
    if let currentUser = try? result.get() {
        let ContainerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tab") as! UITabBarController

        ContainerViewController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
        ContainerViewController.tabBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08281194419, green: 0.0896929279, blue: 0.1466576457, alpha: 1)

        self.view.window?.rootViewController = ContainerViewController
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else if let error = result.error {
        print("Authorization error:", error)
    }
}
```

This happened even though my logs are saying:

> User id: user-one
>   ️  Token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidXNlci1vbmUifQ.AW1xE4VpjzKTpcj3dEX3eLVeXUAoHtaqCEeqDCHYiuo
>     The current user was setupped with id: user-one

Comment: It looks weird. I’ll check.

Comment: Could you check that you setup Client `DetailViewController.viewDidLoad`? Can you add breakpoints?

Comment: I checked in the detail view controller and the User.current is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `User.current` returns a `Client.shared.user as? User`.
Stream Feeds has `GetStream.User` and Activity Feed Components has own `GetStreamActivityFeed.User` with additional properties.

You need to setup user in this way:

```swift
Client.config = .init(apiKey: "ajbbcwn5bxms", appId: "64415")
let token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidXNlci1vbmUifQ.AW1xE4VpjzKTpcj3dEX3eLVeXUAoHtaqCEeqDCHYiuo"

guard let currentUserId = token.userId else { 
    print("Bad token:", token)
    return
}

let user = GetStreamActivityFeed.User(name: "John Doe", id: currentUserId)

Client.shared.setupUser(user, token: token) { result in
    if let currentUser = try? result.get() {
        let ContainerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tab") as! UITabBarController

        ContainerViewController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
        ContainerViewController.tabBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08281194419, green: 0.0896929279, blue: 0.1466576457, alpha: 1)

        self.view.window?.rootViewController = ContainerViewController
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else if let error = result.error {
        print("Authorization error:", error)
    }
}
```